# pathLength and match functions in Allegrograph

Tags: sparql, allegrograph

I'm playing around with property paths and i'm using AllegroGraph Server Edition 4.9. I created a sparql query,

```
select ?y ?x (count(?x) as ?degree) 
where{ 
      {
        ?x $path ?y.
        filter(match($path,foaf:knows))
        filter(pathLength($path) <= 3)
      } 
      UNION 
      {
        ?y $path ?x.
        filter(match($path,foaf:knows))
        filter(pathLength($path) <= 3)
      } 
    } group by ?y ?x.
```

which i expected to see max 3rd degree relatedness with foaf:knows property. But it gives me match and pathLength functions are not recognised. I think this it is an allegrograph problem. Or maybe my query is wrong. Any one tried pathLengh and match functions on allegrograph?

Thanks

Çağdaş

Comment: `pathLength` and `match` are not part of the SPARQL 1.1 standard, can you provide a reference for these?

Comment: [this](http://www.w3.org/2009/sparql/wiki/Feature:PathLength) is reference of these features. So its my bad. Sparql 1.1 does not support these functions yet. But i hope it will. Thanks for response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sparql 1.1 does not include match and pathLength functions. [This](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#propertypaths) is reference of property paths. So its my bad. Hope to see these features in further sparql versions.